# Setting bar button item image to system item programmatically—Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

I have a bar button item set to a custom image from my image assets folder. After launch, once the user presses the button, I want it to change to a system item—the stop (`X`) button. I know how to programmatically change the image of the bar button, but how do I change the image to one of the system items in my code?

Swift 3, Xcode 8 beta 1.

**Edit** Here are the system items I'm referencing:
[image: Xcode system items]

**How can I change my button's image to one of those system items from my code?**

Comment: what is the purpose of changing the BarButtonSystemItem?

Comment: @hariszaman I am making a slide-out side menu (you know, a hamburger menu) and I want the menu button to turn into a big `X` when the menu is opened.

Comment: so just extract X image from iOS assets and when menu is opened change the bar button image

Comment: How do I extract the stop (X) image? Where is it?

Answer (score 3):

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, 
    target: self, 
    action: #selector(yourMethod)
)
```

Change 'add' according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/systemitem

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using iOS 13 & up, you can use the UIImage(systemName:) property. You can search the systemItem names and corresponding images using [Apple's SF Symbols app](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/). Here's an example using the stop X button:

```
barButtonItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "xmark")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to have two buttons (you can set them programmatically or in interface builder), one with the image and another one with the stop behavior. When one is pressed, toggle the visibility of both.

I believe the best option is to do it programmatically, so this is how:

Add two bar button items as class members:

```
private var itemOn: UIBarButtonItem!
private var itemOff: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` set the values as you want (one to have an image, the other to have the normal behavior with the "X"). Then add the `itemOn` button to the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = itemOn
```

Be aware that both should have the same action:

```
self.itemOn.target = self
self.itemOn.action = Selector("toggleVisibleButton:")
self.itemOff.target = self
self.itemOff.action = Selector("toggleVisibleButton:")
```

Then implement the toggleVisibleButton function:

```
func toggleVisibleButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == itemOn {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = itemOff
        // Do something with the button that has the image
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = itemOn
        // Do something with the button that has the X
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 3**:

Set the action like this:

```
self.itemOn.action = #selector(self.toggleVisibleButton(sender:))
```

Comment: Nope. Nice idea, but this doesn't work because I'm talking about a _bar_ button item, and you can't put two on top of each other in the navigation bar. And I can't put a regular button on top of a bar button item because the button goes underneath the nav bar. And I can't have two regular (non-bar) buttons because...well, they both go underneath the nav bar. Any other ideas? If I make the button with image start as a Stop button in my interface builder, can I switch it to its image at app launch and switch it back to stop by restoring it to how it was initially? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I wasn't talking about buttons, the names are just for reference. The idea is to have two bar button items in the navigation bar (actually in the navigation item), one hidden and one visible, and toggle the visibility. Bar button items have a flow layout, meaning that they stick to outer left/right, so when one will become hidden the other will be visible in the same space the other was.

Comment: I can't hide either button! UIBarButtonItems don't have a member `hidden` (or `isHidden` or `hide`) and trying to set them to `nil` has no effect!

Comment: Updated. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I was having a bit of trouble, I'll have to try this in depth maybe tomorrow; sorry for the delay and thank you for your detailed answer!